# Equivalent of WeekDay Function of VB6 in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, vb6, dayofweek, weekday

In VB6 code, I have the following:

```
dim I as Long 

I = Weekday(Now, vbFriday)
```

I want the equivalent in C#. Can any one help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public static int Weekday(DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
{
    return (dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek + 7) % 7;
}
```

This can be called using:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(Weekday(dt, DayOfWeek.Friday));
```

The above outputs:

```
4
```

as Tuesday is 4 days after Friday.

Comment: The return value of the VB6 (and VB.NET) function is 1 based.  `return ((dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek + 7) % 7) + 1;`

Answer (score 4):

You mean the [DateTime.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) property?

```
DayOfWeek dow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes,  Each DateTime value has a built in property called DayOfWeek that returns a enumeration of the same name...

```
DayOfWeek dow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

If you want the integral value just cast the enumeration value to an int.

```
int dow = (int)(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
```

You'll have to add a constant from 1 to 6 and do Mod 7 to realign it to another day besides Sunday, however...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an equivalent of the two argument form of VB's Weekday function.

You could emulate it using something like this;

```
private static int Weekday(DateTime date, DayOfWeek startDay)
{
    int diff;
    DayOfWeek dow = date.DayOfWeek;
    diff = dow - startDay;
    if (diff < 0)
    {
        diff += 7;
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Then calling it like so:

```
int i = Weekday(DateTime.Now, DayOfWeek.Friday);
```

It returns 4 for today, as Tuesday is 4 days after Friday.