# VB to C# conversion DateAndTime equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to convert this VB block to C#.

```
  Public Function AddWorkingDays(ByVal DateIn As DateTime, _
   ByVal ShiftDate As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim b As Integer

    Dim datDate As DateTime = DateIn ' Adds the [ShiftDate] number of working days to DateIn'
    For b = 1 To ShiftDate
        datDate = datDate.AddDays(1)
        ' Loop around until we get the need non-weekend day'
        If Weekday(datDate) = 7 Then
            datDate = datDate.AddDays(2)
        End If
    Next
    Return datDate
End Function
```

So far I've got

```
public DateTime AddWorkingDays(DateTime DateIn, int ShiftDate)
{
    int b = 0;

    DateTime datDate = DateIn;
    // Adds the [ShiftDate] number of working days to DateIn
    for (b = 1; b <= ShiftDate; b++)
    {
        datDate = datDate.AddDays(1);
        // Loop around until we get the need non-weekend day
        if (DateAndTime.Weekday(datDate) == 7)
        {
            datDate = datDate.AddDays(2);
        }
    }
    return datDate;
}
```

I know that there doesn't exist in C# DateAndTime  I just put it in the if statement to complete the block of code. My real problem is getting the IF statement to work. I am not sure if DateTime.Now.Weekday is the same statement as in the previous VB code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400421/equivalent-of-weekday-function-of-vb6-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks NamedJohnny but I looked at that question before posting and didn't understand it.

Comment: The answers you have so far will work, but keep in mind (for more complex issues) that you can always use the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly from C#.  It's especially useful for its financial library.

Comment: Aside: (Counts for both VB and C#) declare the loop variable *inside the loop* and not before. In C#, don’t iterate from 1 to the end of the range +1; instead, iterate from 0 to the end of the range. In other words: `for (int b = 0; b < ShiftDate; b++)`. This is idiomatic and expected; everything else requires an explanation and trips readers of the code up.

Comment: Thanks Konrad I didn't write the original VB code (a previous intern did) and missed that, I've since made the correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Weekday`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.weekday.aspx) returns `7` for `Saturday`, so you can use `DateTime.DayOfWeek` property and compare it to `DayOfWeek.Saturday`:

```
    if (datDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        datDate = datDate.AddDays(2);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use the [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) enumeration, e.g.

```
datDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday
```