# trouble converting function from vb to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to migrate myself to only using C# (was/am a vb.net guy)
I am having trouble converting this vb.net function from a project Im migrating to C#

```
Public Shared Function GetHolidays(ByVal holidaysFile As String) As List(Of Date)
    Dim sAllDates() As String = File.ReadAllLines(holidaysFile)
    Return (From sDate In sAllDates Select CDate(sDate)).ToList()
End Function
```

holidaysFile is a text file that contains items like this;

01/01/2015
01/19/2015
02/16/2015
04/03/2015
05/25/2015
07/03/2015
09/07/2015
11/26/2015
12/25/2015

any help appreciated, and streamreader may be better way to read this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
public static List<DateTime> GetHolidays(string holidaysFile)
{
    string[] sAllDates = File.ReadAllLines(holidaysFile);
    return (from sDate in sAllDates select Convert.ToDateTime(sDate)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: ty, ill accept when available. Is there a C# equivalent to the Weekday function in vb? I can't find one. Using .DayoFWeek in c# returns an int where the vb function returns an enum of DayOfWeek.Sunday etc

Comment: Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400421/equivalent-of-weekday-function-of-vb6-in-c-sharp

Comment: Moreover you can convert enum to int very easily.

Comment: Yes, but I figured why go through the trouble if there was an equivalent already. Ty

Answer (score 2):

This matches the original:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetHolidays(string holidaysFile)
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(holidaysFile).Select(d => Convert.ToDateTime(d)).ToList();
}
```

But it kills me to use a List like that unless there's a real need for it. The code below will allow you to do lazy evaluation, supports only keeping one line in RAM at a time, and often still works with no changes to the calling code — many of the same benefits as using a StreamReader. Note that it's also shorter, and can still be easily converted to a List if needed. While I'm here, since you're coming from a string, you might do better using the `DateTime.Parse()` method:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetHolidays(string holidaysFile)
{
    return File.ReadLines(holidaysFile).Select(d => DateTime.Parse(d));
}
```

As a general rule, you're almost always better off writing code to return an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a `List<T>`. You have very little to lose, because you can *always* just append `.ToList()` to the end of such a function when you need, and much to gain in terms of easier refactoring from one underlying collection type to another and potential performance improvements by reducing RAM use or avoiding looping over items in the List it later turns out you never needed.