# DateAdd and DatePart from VB6 to C#

Tags: c#, datetime, vb6, datetime-format, vb6-migration

Currently working on the conversion of the VB6 to C# but encounters problems regarding DateAdd & DatePart. Hope if anyone is good in VB6 could enlighten me on this. Thanks.

Below are the VB6 codes:

```
dFilterDate2 = DateAdd("d", -4, dFilterDate1)
dFilterDate3 = DateAdd("y", -(DatePart("y", dFilterDate1) - 1), dFilterDate1)
dFilterDate4 = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, dFilterDate3)
dFilterDate5 = DateAdd("d", Weekday(CDate(dFilterDate1)) - 1, CDate(DateAdd("ww", Format(CDate(dFilterDate1), "ww") - 1, CDate(CDate(dFilterDate4) - Weekday(CDate(dFilterDate4))))))
```

And below are my code in C#.

```
dFilterDate2 = dFilterDate1.AddDays(-4);
dFilterDate3 = dFilterDate1.AddYears(-dFilterDate1.DayOfYear-1);
dFilterDate4 = dFilterDate3.AddYears(-1);
dFilterDate5 = ?;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of WeekDay Function of VB6 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400421/equivalent-of-weekday-function-of-vb6-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What is `dFilterDate1` and what is an answer in VB6 for `dFilterDate5` given some input so this can be tested?

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for provides the link, however it looks strange after combination with DateAdd & Weekday.

Comment: @eglease Thanks for the comment. `dFilterDate1` can be any date, but `dFilterDate5` looks complicated for me with the combination of the DateAdd & WeekDay hence I am unable to figure it out

Comment: What is the business rule?   Do you know why it was written this way?

Comment: @eglease That's no such document for me to refer since the system has been used for at least 10 years(VB6) and it will be decommissioned soon.

Comment: I am going to try to solve this.  May take a moment but I got it working in VB6.

Comment: @eglease Yep, it's the original source code from the old project, should work well but seem complicated for me and difficult to re-write it to other language

Comment: We are in the same boat.  I have to rewrite/refactor/re-engineer multiple VB6 project into C# and/or Go and/or SQL.

Comment: The conversion for dFilterDate3 is incorrect. The original code will (simply?) produce a date of january 1 with the year that dFilterDate3 has. For instance, a date of 9/23/2021 will calculate to 1/1/2021. The converted code line will subtract from the year the number of days of the day of the year, less an additional one; a date of 9/23/2021 (day 266) will produce 9/23/1754.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me a while but this is what I go.

First, `dFilterDate3` is not correct.  It is not years but days based on the day of the year.

```
var dFilterDate1 = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2); 
var dFilterDate2 = dFilterDate1.AddDays(-4);
var dFilterDate3 = dFilterDate1.AddDays(-(dFilterDate1.DayOfYear - 1));
var dFilterDate4 = dFilterDate3.AddYears(-1);
```

Second, C# does not have a built-in equivalents for weeks so I had to copy some helper functions from SO.

I also had to breakdown the code into lots of temp variables and this is what I got:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dFilterDate1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4); // UTC to EST for apples to apples testing
        var dFilterDate2 = dFilterDate1.AddDays(-4);
        var dFilterDate3 = dFilterDate1.AddDays(-(dFilterDate1.DayOfYear - 1));
        var dFilterDate4 = dFilterDate3.AddYears(-1);
        
        
        var dFilterDate5temp1 = ((int)dFilterDate1.DayOfWeek + 1) - 1; // this is for readability.  -1 is needed for C# vs VB
        var dFilterDate5temp2 = (int)dFilterDate4.DayOfWeek + 1;
        var dFilterDate5temp3 = dFilterDate4.AddDays(-dFilterDate5temp2);
        var dFilterDate5temp4 = GetWeekOfYear(dFilterDate1);
        var dFilterDate5temp5 = dFilterDate5temp3.AddDays(7 * (dFilterDate5temp4 - 1));
        var dFilterDate5 = dFilterDate5temp5.AddDays(dFilterDate5temp1);
        
        
        Console.WriteLine(dFilterDate1);
        Console.WriteLine(dFilterDate2);
        Console.WriteLine(dFilterDate3);
        Console.WriteLine(dFilterDate4);
        Console.WriteLine(dFilterDate5);
    }

    public static int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime dt)
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
        Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
        return cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

You can test it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/LFYfyG

I get this as output:

```
9/23/2021 11:58:07 AM
9/19/2021 11:58:07 AM
1/1/2021 11:58:07 AM
1/1/2020 11:58:07 AM
9/23/2020 11:58:07 AM
```

And this is from the VB6:

[image: VB6 Results]

This is my VB6 code that shows how I broke this down

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()

   Dim dFilterDate1 As String
   Dim dFilterDate5temp As Integer
   
   dFilterDate1 = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Now) ' I tried many different values for this - this is one year from now so it is not exactly the same as the C# example
   dFilterDate2 = DateAdd("d", -4, dFilterDate1)
   dFilterDate3 = DateAdd("y", -(DatePart("y", dFilterDate1) - 1), dFilterDate1)
   dFilterDate4 = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, dFilterDate3)
   dFilterDate5 = DateAdd("d", Weekday(CDate(dFilterDate1)) - 1, CDate(DateAdd("ww", Format(CDate(dFilterDate1), "ww") - 1, CDate(CDate(dFilterDate4) - Weekday(CDate(dFilterDate4))))))
   
   dFilterDate5temp1 = Weekday(CDate(dFilterDate1), vbSunday) - 1
   
   dFilterDate5temp2 = Weekday(CDate(dFilterDate4), vbSunday)
   
   dFilterDate5temp3 = CDate(dFilterDate4) - dFilterDate5temp2
   
   dFilterDate5temp4 = Format(CDate(dFilterDate1), "ww")
   
   dFilterDate5temp5 = DateAdd("ww", dFilterDate5temp4 - 1, CDate(dFilterDate5temp3))
   
   dFilterDate5New = DateAdd("d", dFilterDate5temp1, CDate(dFilterDate5temp5))

   
   Text1.Text = dFilterDate1
   Text2.Text = dFilterDate2
   Text3.Text = dFilterDate3
   Text4.Text = dFilterDate4
   Text5.Text = dFilterDate5
   Text6.Text = dFilterDate5New

End Sub
```

The hardest parts were `Weekday` and `WeekOfTheYear` that do not exist directly in C#.  Some of the solutions I found on SO were wrong so it lead me down the wrong path.  Note that the answer will be different based on what is the first day of the week.

**Update:**  I just noticed that I was testing the VB code with last year so the values are not the same.  Here is the VB6 code with the values from `Now`.
[image: VB6 Results from Now]

Also, VB6 is running on my laptop in the EST timezone while dotnetfiddle is always UTC.  I just subtracted 4 hours so the times would be the same.

Comment: You can put all of C# code on one line but I do not recommend it as it make is very difficult to debug.

Comment: Your `+1) -1 ` is unnecessary, also it’s straight forward framework code that doesn’t differ between languages.

Comment: It is not necessary.  I put it there to show that I am doing it on purpose.  I belive the constants are different between vb6 and .net.